# ELK + REDIS - Duplicando dados

Tags: log, redis, linux, elasticsearch

Fala galera,

preciso de um help...

Tenho os seguintes arquivos de configuração do Logstash:

#### agent.conf

```
 input {
  log4j {
    type => "bdj"
    port => 25827
  }
}

filter{
    json{
        source => "message"
    }
    
}

output {
  stdout { 
    codec => rubydebug
  }
  redis {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    data_type => "list"
    key => "logstash"
  }
}
```

Este **agent.conf** recebe os logs via tcp e encaminha para o redis.

#### central.conf

```
input {
  redis {
    host => "localhost"
    type => "redis-input"
    data_type => "list"
    key => "logstash"
  }
}

filter{
  json{
    source => "message"
  } 
}

output {
  stdout { }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost"
    index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }

}
```

O **central.conf** por sua vez, captura os dados do redis e encaminha para o elastichsarch.

O Problema é que os dados estão sendo duplicados, como se estivessem em loop,ou algo do gênero.

Estou rodando o logstash em um Debian, como um serviço.

```
root@logs:~# uname -a
Linux logs 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.78-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Alguma luz?

Answer (score 1):

O registro duplicado não é o registro log fantasma como acontece com servidor SCALA?

"Uma solução alternativa para evitar registros de log duplicados após a reinicialização do logstash é configurar o parâmetro sincedb_path no plug-in de arquivo como /dev/null, indicando, portanto, para o logstash, que ignore o rastreamento da última posição monitorada do arquivo e sempre inicie o monitoramento a partir do fim do arquivo. No entanto, isso fará com que o logstash ignore todas as atualizações feitas no arquivo de log enquanto o agente logstash estiver inativo."

Veja esse help da IBM:

[Duplicação de registros de log no servidor SCALA](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPFMY_1.3.2/com.ibm.scala.doc/extend/t_iwa_extend_logstash_duprecsonserver.html?lang=pt-br)